# как исправить кодировку в Python?

Tags: python

```
# pip install beautifulsoup4 lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("blank/index.html") as file:
    src = file.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")

title = soup.title
print(title)
print(title)
print(title.string)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала, вы пытаете манипулировать открытым файлом вне зоны его видимости.

Лучше открыть файл так:

```
src = open("blank/index.html", "r")
```

Далее нужно добавить метод декодирования в объявлении объекта soup

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(src.read().decode('utf-8'), "lxml")
```

Comment: Всегда считал, что работа с файлами предпочтительнее через `with`. Ибо не надо опасаться, что забудешь сделать `close`. Так что в вопросе запись более правильная.

Comment: "Для начала, вы пытаете манипулировать открытым файлом вне зоны его видимости." - вообще-то нет, значение переменной src вполне доступно вне блока with. "Лучше открыть файл так:" - нет, лучше через with. Вот это `src.read().decode('utf-8')` вообще будет работать только если файл открыт в бинарном режиме, а `"r"` - это обычный текстовый режим.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('blank/index.html', encoding='utf-8') as file:
```

Comment: а это уже ответ? тогда, пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]